# Time complexity and height of disjoint sets using array in C

Tags: c, time-complexity, disjoint-sets

I found a quiz about the time complexity of disjointed sets when using an array.

*Suppose we have nodes that are numbered from 0 to n-1. All we need is an array named parent, where the value of parent[i] is the ID of the parent node i. If node i is a root node, parent[i] is -1. Below is an example of disjointed sets and their array representation.*

If there are nodes with ten numbers 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 and they are making disjointed sets.

- 0 is parent of 6,7,8 and 6,7,8 are siblings
- 4 is parent of 1,9 and 1,9 are siblings
- 2 is parent of 3,5 and 3,5 are siblings

Then the array called parent[i] will be like {-1,4,-1,2,-1,2,0,0,0,4} and there are two basic operations about disjoint sets : Find(i) and Union(i,j)

```
int simpleFind(int i) {
    for( ; parent[i] >= 0; i = parent[i])
       ;
    return i;
}

void simpleUnion(int i, int j) { /* i and j must be roots */
    parent[i] = j;
}
```

There are two questions I want some help with!

- 1. Suppose we start with initial disjoint sets of n nodes all individually separated.(There are only nodes from 0,1,2,3, n-1 not
     being related to each other) Then, we consecutively call
     *simpleUnion* on arbitrary two trees until eventually, the sets become a single tree. What is the maximum height of the resulting single tree? Use the following definition on the height of a tree. ※ Height of a
     tree – The height of a tree is the number of edges on the longest downward path between the root and a leaf. If the tree has a single node (only the root node), its height is zero.
- 2. What is the worst-case time complexity of *simpleFind*, when function *simpleUnion* is used for union operation on disjoint sets?? with n nodes? Use the Big-O notation.

I think the answer to the first question is n-1 when these nodes are connected as one line. I can not figure out the second question. Is it o(log n)?

Answer (score 1):

### Question 1.

I guess the answer to the first question is `n-1` as OP suspects. Imagine a sequence of operations:

```
simpleUnion(0,1);
simpleUnion(1,2);
...
simpleUnion(n-2,n);
```

The parent of node `0` would be `1`, parent of `1` would be `2` and so on. The tree would degenerate to a list of length `n`.

### Question 2.

Run `simpleFind(0)` on the tree from `Question 1`.
Loop would iterate over all nodes of the tree. Thus the complexity is `O(n)`.